# Dojo cannot parse custom date time format

Tags: javascript, datetime, dojo

I am attempting to use Dojo locale date parser but am having a heck of a time. Every time I do it it returns `null`.

I even forced a value of `"test"` to the variable outside of the function to eliminate an undefined variable scope, and it still returns `null`.

```
var djLastString = "test";
require(["dojo/date/locale"], function(locale) {
    djLastString = locale.parse("20180511 18", {
        datePattern: 'yyyyMMdd',
        timePattern: 'HH',
        selector: 'date'
    });
});
console.log(djLastString);
```

result: `null`

Comment: what do you want to achieve here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert string into Date so , in your case you have to specify the exact [pattern](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/date/locale/format.html#dojo-date-locale-format-attributes) that goes with your string ,

Your string is `20180511 18` so the datePattern should be `yyyyMMdd HH` ( H `->` hours ) instead of `yyyyMMdd`

See below snippet

```js
var djLastString = "test";
require(["dojo/date/locale"], function(locale) {
    djLastString = locale.parse("20180511 18", {
        datePattern: 'yyyyMMdd HH',
        timePattern: 'HH',
        selector: 'date'
    });
    
    console.log(djLastString);
    console.log(djLastString.getTime());
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#accContainer {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
  dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: true,
    async: true
  };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```